# Is there any chance of an address returned by mmap(2) clashing with the heap?

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, mmap, sbrk

If I allocate some pages using `mmap(2)`, without providing an address hint, and later allocate some memory using `malloc(3)` / `calloc(3)`, is there a chance that `malloc` calls `sbrk(2)` and grows the heap in a way that it overlaps onto the address returned by my earlier call to `mmap` or is `mmap` always guaranteed to return an address far away from the heap or stack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no risk of a clash, not in [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) and probably not in any implementation using paging -- and I doubt there would be an `mmap()` on systems without paging. I can't tell you now (because I just don't know it) which virtual addresses `mmap()` uses: probably indeed far enough from the heap. For the physical memory: `sbrk()` will sooner or later provoke a *page fault* and of course, your OS will take care to map you a page that **isn't** in use. `mmap()` works on whole pages anyways...

**edit** as [rodrigo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4045048/mijo) points out correctly, *big* requests to `malloc()` are served using `mmap()` anyways. So for the small requests being served using `sbrk()`, you don't have to expect *too* many pagefaults.

Answer (score 1):

No, you will not have overlaps.

That does not mean that they will be far away, they may be just next to the other. But if you respect the limits of the allocated memory all will be fine.

Note that the glib implementation of `malloc()` will use anonymous `mmap()` calls to satisfy requests for big chunks of memory.